# Normal open subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(L / K)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L / K$ be Galois extension and $H$ be a subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(L / K)$.
Suppose that $K$ is a subfield of $L$ that is invariant by $H$.
Show that $HN = \operatorname{Gal}(L / K)$ for any normal open subgroup $N$ of $\operatorname{Gal}(L / K)$.

Comment: You are using $K$ for different things

Comment: Thank you. The text was strange, so I edited it. The $K$s that appear in the text are the same. I think it will probably work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is your question doesn't make sense. My guess to repair it:

Let $L / K$ be an infinite Galois extension and $H$ a subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(L / K)$.
$L^H$ is the subfield of $L$ fixed by $H$.
Show that $HN = \operatorname{Gal}(L / L^H)$ for any normal open subgroup $N$ of $\operatorname{Gal}(L / L^H)$.

Proof: $N=\operatorname{Gal}(L/L^N)$ and $L^N/L^H$ is a finite extension and $L^H$ is the subfield fixed by $HN/N$, whence $\operatorname{Gal}(L/L^H)/\operatorname{Gal}(L/L^N)=\operatorname{Gal}(L^N/L^H)=HN/N$ so that $HN\to\operatorname{Gal}(L/L^H)$ is surjective ie. $HN=\operatorname{Gal}(L/L^H)$.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.
I don't understand exactly what the elements of $HN / N$ are.
I think it means that $HN / N$ is equated with the $Gal (L / K)$ subgroup.
How can I define injective $HN / N \to Gal (L / K)$?

Comment: $N$ is normal thus $HN =\{ h \in H,n\in N\}$ is a group and $HN/N$ is the quotient by its subgroup $N$.